# Producing a set of matrices in MAGMA

Tags: matrices, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

As part of my work I need to define the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ (considered as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$), such that each row and column of the matrix sums to $n$.

Is there an easy way to do this in MAGMA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea towards a solution.  It only works (practically) until $n=3$ on my computer, because with $n=4$ it has to sift through $5^{16}$ different matrices.  Perhaps someone can refine my method, or introduce one that is not so crude, ie, one that uses a little more theory than I have used.  Essentially, all I've done is defined a function NSumMatrix($m$) which returns true if $m$ has the desired property.

First, define a RowSum($A$,$i$) function as follows:

> RowSum:=function(A,i)
>
> return &+[A[i,j]:j in [1..Nrows(A)]];
>
> end function;

Define a function similarly for the column sum.  Then, define the following aforementioned function:

> NSumMatrix:=function(m)
>
> n:=Nrows(m);
>
> a:=1;
>
> b:=1;
>
> z:=ChangeRing(m,IntegerRing());
>
> while a le n and RowSum(z,a) eq n do
>
> a:=a+1;
>
> end while;
>
> if a le n then
>
> return false;
>
> end if;
>
> while b le n and ColumnSum(z,b) eq n do
>
> b:=b+1;
>
> end while;
>
> if b le n then
>
> return false;
>
> else
>
> return true;
>
> end if;
>
> end function;

Now, define a matrix algebra:

> M:=MatrixAlgebra(Integers(n+1),n);

And finally, construct the desired set using the function:

> S:={x:x in M|NSumMatrix(x)};

For $n=3$, if you print $S$, you'll find all $55$ matrices whose rows and column sums are all $3$.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is definitely an improvement on the method that I was using. As you say, hopefully someone can come up with a theoretical answer as well, as I'm sure that one must exist.